# ASP.NET Adding gridview to panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, panel

I am completely new to ASP.NET. I am building 4 pages. One should import `gridview` to the page. And there is a class that saves it. And in another page I should get that `gridview`. But when I load the page I get error:

> `RegisterRequiresControlState` can only be called before and during `PreRender`.

Here is my code for page load:

```html
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Data._grid != null)
    {
         p1.Controls.Add(Data._grid);
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

For aspx:

```html
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="p1"></asp:Panel>
```

Here code for saving `gridview` to class:

```html
protected void import_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filepath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"].ToString();
        string filename = string.Empty;
        string[] allowedfile = { ".xls", ".xlsx" };
        string filetext = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        if (!allowedfile.Contains(filetext))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            int filesize = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            if (filesize <= 1048576)
            {
                filename = Path.GetFileName(Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName));
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filepath) + filename);
                string _filepath = Server.MapPath(filepath) + filename;
                OleDbConnection con = null;
                if (filetext == ".xls")
                {
                    con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + _filepath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0");
                }
                else if (filetext == ".xlsx")
                {
                    con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + _filepath + "';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
                }
                con.Open();
                DataTable dt = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                string get_sheet = dt.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
                OleDbCommand excelcommand = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [" + get_sheet + @"]", con);
                OleDbDataAdapter exceladapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(excelcommand);
                DataSet exceldataset = new DataSet();
                exceladapter.Fill(exceldataset);
                con.Close();
                grid.DataSource = exceldataset;
                grid.DataBind();
                Data._grid = grid;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not import control from one page to other page. You can make reusable user controls .ascx and use them in different pages.

In you case you can make a web user control that has GridView and add that user control in both pages as we do with asp.net web controls. Read more about user controls in this MSDN article [ASP.NET User Controls Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I got you!